# Birefringince in 2D array of masses and springs

Tags: waves, vibrations, dispersion, birefringence

Assume a 2D square array of masses with mass $m$ connected by springs with constant $\kappa$. Then the equation of motion for small perturbations in the plane of the array to the mass at $(l,n)$ is

$$
\ddot{\vec{\psi}}_{l,n} = \Omega^2(\vec{\psi}_{l+1,n}-2\vec{\psi}_{l,n} + \vec{\psi}_{l-1,n})+\Omega^2(\vec{\psi}_{l,n+1}-2\vec{\psi}_{l,n} + \vec{\psi}_{l,n-1})
$$
where $\Omega^2=\kappa/m$. The normal modes are
$$
\vec{\psi}_{l,n,\vec{k}}=\vec{A}_{\vec{k}}e^{i\left[a(k_xl+k_yn)-\omega t\right]}
$$
where $a$ is the separation between masses at equilibrium.

Perturbations have 2 polarizations here, for example $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$.

How can I make this system exhibit birefringince? I.e., how can I make waves moving with polarization $\hat{x}$ move at a different velocity that with polarization $\hat{y}$?

First guess would be to change the spring constant of let's say the springs along the $y$ direction to $\kappa'$. Then the equation of motion would be

$$
\ddot{\vec{\psi}}_{l,n} = \Omega^2(\vec{\psi}_{l+1,n}-2\vec{\psi}_{l,n} + \vec{\psi}_{l-1,n})+{\Omega'}^2(\vec{\psi}_{l,n+1}-2\vec{\psi}_{l,n} + \vec{\psi}_{l,n-1})
$$

However, a plane wave of the form $\vec{\psi}=\vec{A}e^{iak_xl-\omega t}$, i.e. moving at the $\hat{x}$ direction, will only feel the springs with constant $\kappa$, no matter if the polarization is along the $\hat{x}$ or $\hat{y}$ direction. In other words, the dispersion relation does not depend on the polarization.

How can I make it sensitive to the polarization (and not the propagation direction)?

Comment: Im only familiar with optical birefringence. In this case the two polarizations are transverse to the propagation direction. This requires three dimensions. Is it know that 2d waves/media can exhibit birefringence?

Comment: You can take $\Omega^2=\Omega’^2$. However, for polarization dependence, you’ll need them to be matrices rather than scalars. In general, you can assume them to be symmetric, so using the spectral theorem, you can reduce to the diagonal case. For birefringence, you only need $2$ different eigenvalues and up to a rotation assume that the $z$ line and $xy$ plane are principal directions.